# Extending Loader

Tags: actionscript-3, extending-classes

I´m trying to extend the Loader class.

I want to store a variable on it.

Example:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Loader;

public class MyLoader extends Loader
{
    private var _typeOfGallery:String

    public function MyLoader()
    {
        super()
    }

    public function set typeOfGallery(value:String):void
    {
        _typeOfGallery = value
    }

    public function get typeOfGallery():String
    {
        return _typeOfGallery
    }
}

}
```

Then I´m using like this:

```
var loader:MyLoader = new MyLoader()
loader.typeOfGallery = 'games'
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded)

function loaded(e:Event):void{
trace(e.target.typeOfGallery)
}
```

I´m receiving this error:

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property typeOfGallery not found in flash.display.LoaderInfo and has no pattern value.

(I have translated from portuguese to english the error message)

How could I extend Loader so I don´t receive this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Loader` does not dispatch the `Event.COMPLETE` event. You should listen to

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded)
```

and then get your `MyLoader` with

```
function loaded(e:Event):void{
   trace(((e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo).loader as MyLoader).typeOfGallery);
}
```

In your code, `e.target` is a `LoaderInfo` because the `COMPLETE` event bubbles to the `Loader` itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.typeOfGallery = 'games'
```

IS WRONG - you want to go for the loader not for its contentLoaderInfo...

```
loader.typeOfGallery = 'games'
```

trace(e.target.typeOfGallery) should work cause its a reference to the loader!!